# How to create columns in plain html

Tags: html

I am new to html, is there a way to create columns in plain html, without using CSS, Bootstrap, Jquery or any other frameworks.?

Comment: @RajaKhoury Thank you for your reply, but I wanted to define columns by using div's

Comment: That would require some CSS. May I know why it is not possible to use any CSS ? as far as I'm aware it is not possible.

Comment: Column is any block with display: block;

Answer (score 5):

You can use the HTML `table` element if you do want to use any CSS. See below

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define columns by using div's , then you have to use CSS to allot space. If you strictly oppose CSS then as @Raja Khoury said you have to use table.

Or else div along with CSS :

```
<div id="wrap" style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">
    <div id="left_col" style="float:left; width:300px;">
        LEFT
    </div>
    <div id="right_col" style="float:right; width:300px;">
        RIGHT
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/h8r22mmr/

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
  Add more columns .........
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>

    Add more columns .........
  </tr>
</table>
```